# Device Disconnect After some time & Unable to get characteristic

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral

**I know disconnect error mentioned is asked many times on stack but answers accepted are not actual solution to issue**

I am trying to connect MI Band 3 with my swift App. It get connected successfully but after some time it get disconnected automatically

```
Error:  Error Domain=CBErrorDomain Code=7 "The specified device has disconnected from us." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The specified device has disconnected from us
```

**My App Requirement: I need to get heart rate and walking distance from Apple Watch, Fitbit and MI Smart Watch**

I have tried connecting same MI Band on multiple device result is same. But that specific MI band work perfectly with their own app

```
--> Connect Device - Kept reference of connected Device
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        print("Connected With Peripheral: \(peripheral)")
        selectedPeripheral=peripheral
        self.delegate?.scannedPeripherals(Is: peripheral)

        /// Discover Services Provided By Device
        selectedPeripheral?.delegate=self
        selectedPeripheral?.discoverServices([heartRateServiceCBUUID])
    }

---> After Discovering services With heart Rate CBUUID
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
        guard let characteristics = service.characteristics else { return }
        selectedPeripheral=peripheral
        for char in characteristics {
            print("Characterstics: \(char)")
            if char.properties.contains(.read) {
            }
            if char.properties.contains(.notify) {
                /// ------------- Setting Notify to true but not never call required delegates ----------------
                peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: char)
                print("\(char.uuid): properties contains .notify")
                peripheral.readValue(for: char)
            }
        }
    }


Calculating BPM from delegate
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        switch characteristic.uuid {
        case bodySensorLocationCharacteristicCBUUID:
            let bodySensorLocation = bodyLocation(from: characteristic)
            print(bodySensorLocation)
        default:
            /// --------- here characteristic value is nil --------------
            let bpm = heartRate(from: characteristic)
            print("BPM: \(bpm)")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In `func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?)`

Try to remove `peripheral.readValue(for: char)` and test again!

Answer (score -1):

Just remove this line

```
peripheral.readValue(for: char)
```

Now everything will work as expected